# How do I configure a Apache proxy for my Couchapp?

Tags: apache, proxy, couchdb, httpd.conf, couchapp

I want to realize a proxy through a **Apache Webserver 2.2.14** on **Ubuntu 10.04.1**. for a Couchapp on **Couchdb 1.0.1** and I'm not experienced with that. The proxy should also redirect to another couchdb-database and some other pathes in Apaches www-path. The target is, to call the Couchapp (index.html) on sub.something.de.

My Questions are:

1. It works, but is there a smarter way to do that? My own way looks for me like a Workaround.
2. A problem is, when I do a logout with couchdb-api, I get another dialog to login from Apache. After I login, I can logout ;) The problem is, that the uri, I call for logout, looks like that _:_@sub.something.de and this don't match with my Proxy-Configuration. What is the solution?

Here is my httpd.conf Configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "/var/www/Something"
 ServerName something
 ServerAlias sub.something.de

 AllowEncodedSlashes On
 ProxyRequests Off
 ProxyPreserveHost Off
 ProxyVia On
 KeepAlive Off

 <Proxy *>
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Something Login"
  AuthUserFile /home/user/.couchdb_htpasswd
  Require valid-user

  Order deny,allow     
  Deny from all
  Allow from 127.0.0.1
  Satisfy Any
 </Proxy>   

 ProxyPass /something_data http://localhost:5984/something_data/ nocanon
 ProxyPass /data http://localhost:5984/something/_design/prototype/data nocanon
 ProxyPass /css http://localhost:5984/something/_design/prototype/css nocanon
 ProxyPass /vendor http://localhost:5984/something/_design/prototype/vendor nocanon
 ProxyPass /js http://localhost:5984/something/_design/prototype/js nocanon
 ProxyPass /font http://localhost:5984/something/_design/prototype/font nocanon
 ProxyPass /php http://localhost/dev/something/php nocanon
 ProxyPass /uploads http://localhost/dev/something/uploads nocanon
 ProxyPass /_uuids http://localhost:5984/_uuids nocanon
 ProxyPass /_session http://localhost:5984/_session nocanon
 ProxyPass /_users http://localhost:5984/_users nocanon

 ProxyPass /_users !
 ProxyPass /_uuids !
 ProxyPass /_session !
 ProxyPass /php !
 ProxyPass /uploads !
 ProxyPass /font !
 ProxyPass /data !
 ProxyPass /css !
 ProxyPass /vendor !
 ProxyPass /js !
 ProxyPass /something_data !

 ProxyPass /  http://localhost:5984/something/_design/prototype/index.html nocanon
 ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5984/something/_design/prototype/
 RequestHeader unset Authorization

 ErrorLog "/home/user/logs/couchdb_error_log"
 CustomLog "/home/user/logs/couchdb_access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Set value of urlPrefix in couch.js

```
#vi /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
ProxyPass /_db/  http://localhost:5984/
ProxyPassReverse /_db/ http://localhost:5984/


#vi  /usr/share/couchdb/www/script/couch.js
CouchDB.urlPrefix = '/_db/';
```